# The fastest way to run Starcraft 2 offline?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

I need to play Custom Games in offline mode.

As shown here on [Battle.NET](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/running-starcraft-ii-in-offline-mode) and [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108398/can-starcraft-2-be-played-offline/108401#108401), to play in offline mode we have to disconnect the internet connection. The problem is this process can take anywhere from about 30 seconds to several minutes.

Is there a faster way to get to Offline Mode immediately or as fast as we can? E.g. some setting that can be tweaked to turn down the waiting time for the connection?

Comment: Why my questions get down-voted so much every one ^^ ?

Comment: This is probably because this question doesn't look like it could benefit anyone, and is pure curiosuty. StackExchange strives to be a useful archive of knowledge for many people, and no one likes to spend time answering questions someone is just too lazy to google themselves. Can you please describe why switching SC2 to offline mode is important, and why do you need to do this so often you want to optimize the process?

Comment: The reason I need the offline mode is that I play offline a lot from my city Saigon, Vietnam.

Comment: The connection to Blizzard servers is ensured to be not good all the time here

Comment: Why don't you just play in online mode? if you're playing the offline stuff such as campaign which doesn't use your connection what is the difference going to be?

Comment: @Aequitas: maybe the Blizzards are blocked, for example via proxy. If it tries for N times, you probably want to let early on know that it's not going to work -> start offline

Comment: What step exactly is taking 30 seconds to several minutes?

Comment: @Aequitas As I shared above, the lagging connection is very bothering me when play online; I even get kicked out in the middle of a game.

Comment: The time spent to go on offline mode is estimated by me. The step is just start the game, hit play and wait.

Comment: So then don't play online? I don't understand, you can still access offline content while in online mode, your connection won't matter in this case. So there's no need to log into offline mode, you can just log in as normal and then only play offline modes

Comment: If you're talking about waiting for that connection box with the progress bar, you can just click cancel, which will then cause the game to load and you can then log into offline mode.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I can play offline when I am online/connected. How to go offline when connected then?

Comment: just don't play online modes, if you play campaign, it will be offline already.  or are you saying that you disconnect from campaign?

Comment: I can confirm that the game runs Campaign just fine when the connection is unstable. At Heart of the Swarm launch the servers were overloaded, so after I played through the campaign without any lag, I just missed half the achievements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the attempting to connect box that appears when clicking play from battle.net without a connection by just clicking cancel. There's no need to wait. This will cause Starcraft 2 to launch immediately and you can log on from there. (Note: you have to have logged on at least once before in online mode)

However there doesn't sound like there is any need for you to launch the game in offline mode. You can still access all the same offline content from when the game is connected. If you lose connection sometimes, it will only affect you if you are playing online modes, such as ladder. If however you only play offline modes, such as campaign, when you are connected, you should not be able to be disconnected and dropped from games.

Comment: Hi @Aequitas, I need to play custom games in offline mode not the compain game

Comment: Then does the first suggestion do as you want?

Comment: Yeah it works - just simply like that! Thank you @Aequitas!